# Set locktimeout using JDBC for MySQl

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

Is there a way to set the locktimeout on SQL queries from the ConnectorJ JDBC driver. I'm looking for something like the SQL server:

```
 connectURL = url + domain + ":1433;" + "databaseName="+databaseName+ ";lockTimeout=" + lockTimeOut;
```

driver parameter.

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL doesn't seem to have such an option, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post a solution that I found for this, which I hope helps someone: for MySQl you're looking to add a line to your conf file. On Linux, SystemD, this resides inside /etc/my.cnf

Add this line to the [mysqld] entries

innodb_lock_wait_timeout=1

That's it. Lock timeout is now set to one second.

Comment: The downside of this is that it applies to all connections.